# Ubuntu 18.04 can't install old mysql 5.6

Tags: 18.04, mysql

I'm trying to install an older version of mysql [5.6.45] by running this command:

```
apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
```

But i'm getting this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.6 : Depends: initscripts but it is not installable
                Depends: sysv-rc (>= 2.88dsf-24) but it is not installable 
or
                         file-rc (>= 0.8.16) but it is not installable
                Recommends: libhtml-template-perl but it is not going to be 
installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If i run:

```
apt-get install initscripts
```

I'm getting this message:

```
Package initscripts is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  bootlogd util-linux sysvinit-utils

E: Package 'initscripts' has no installation candidate
```

What should i do to be able to install mysql 5.6 (5.6.45 preferred)?

P.S: i'm using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I am also getting the same problem. Is there any solution?